# ImageResizer watermark applies base image instead of watermark image

Tags: c#, watermark, imageresizer

I'm trying to use the watermark feature in imageresizer but when applying a watermark the image itself is being added on top of the original image instead of the watermark image.

If I navigate to the original image it works, using this url:

```
localhost/globalassets/resources/horse.jpg
```

Original image:

[image]

If I then add the watermark parameter ?watermark=test1 to the url like this:

```
localhost/globalassets/resources/horse.jpg?watermark=test1
```

I get this result.

[image]

If I navigate to the watermark image it can be viewed, for example by navigation to: `localhost/Styles/Images/Watermarks/watermark.png`

This is my config:

```
  <resizer>
<licenses>
  <license>
    I have a license here
  </license>
</licenses>
<plugins>
  <add name="Presets" />
  <add name="EPiServerBlobReaderPlugin" />
  <add name="DiskCache" />
  <add name="Watermark" />
</plugins>
<watermarks>
   <otherimages path="~/Styles/Images/Watermarks" left="20" top="20" width="80%" height="80%" drawAs="overlay" />
   <image name="test1" path="~/Styles/Images/Logos/watermark.png" right="20" bottom="20" width="80%" height="80%" drawAs="overlay" />
</watermarks>
<diskcache dir="~/imagecache" subfolders="256" />
<presets onlyAllowPresets="false">
  <preset name="large" settings="width=1220" />
  <preset name="gallerythumb" settings="width=300" />
</presets>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this happen even if you remove `<otherimages>` from the XML? `<otherimages>` has been deprecated for five years due to poor design.

Comment: Hi @NathanaelJones removing <otherimages> makes no difference I'm afraid. I tired using it also and that creates the same result as posted above.

Comment: Have you used a cache-breaker to make sure the result isn't cached?

Comment: I have simply removed the cached files on disk and seen that new ones are created. Is that enough? I have also changed parameters for example width and height and seen that the image has changed.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with all plugins except Watermark removed?

Comment: If I remove Presets and DiskCache from the config it is still behaving the same. But if I remove the EpiserverBlobReaderPlugin then suddenly the watermarks are no longer applied? If I use a watermark parameter to my url the original image is simply shown, not even text based watermarks (that have worked previously) works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually the EPiServerBlobReader plugin which did not use the virtualPath provided from ImageResizer but always used the routed content as source.
After changing the plugin everything worked as expected.